# Process a file containing X and Y coordinates, using a function in Python

Tags: python

I'm working in BBedit, on a Mac.
I can do this in two separate operations, but I want to combine them
i.e. go straight from origin.txt to ultimateTarget.txt.
The operation *sequence* isn't important.
New to Python, I'd prefer a simple solution.
It's just a concept atm - it doesn't have to be pure or elegant - just basic.

origin.txt

```
X3.
X2.5 Y-1.
X2. Y-2.
X5. Y-5.
X-3.
...
```

temporaryTarget.txt

```
C3.
C2.5 Z1.
C2. Z2.
C5. Z5.
C-3.
...
```

ultimateTarget.txt

```
C42.972
C35.81 Z1.
C28.648 Z2.
C71.62 Z5.
C-42.972
...
```

Operation 1 - Process the whole file (this works)

```
# Replace X with C, and replace Y- with Z
readFile = open("origin.txt", "rt")
writeFile = open("temporaryTarget.txt", "wt")

for line in readFile:
    writeFile.write(line.replace('X', 'C').replace('Y-', 'Z'))

readFile.close()
writeFile.close()
```

Operation 2 - function mmToDegrees
(this doesn't work on the whole file yet - it only does one value at a time)

```
# Convert mm movements [letter C] to degrees, based on a radius
import math
cylynderDiameter = 8
decimalPlaces = 3
rad = cylynderDiameter/2 # equation below uses a radius
C = 3. # mm linear move - used as arc length in equation below # this line won't be in the final solution

def mmToDegrees(): # define function
    global C # to prevent UnboundLocalError
    C = round((C/rad)*(180/math.pi), decimalPlaces) #convert mm move to angle in degrees
mmToDegrees() # call the function
print (C) # this line won't be in the final solution
```

So, Operation 2 needs to go *inside* Operation 1

Comment: Please clarify how X3 is converted to C42.972.   Is that formula for changing ```3``` to ```42.972```?

Comment: Yes. X is replaced by C, then converted by: C = round((C/rad)*(180/math.pi),decimalPlaces)

Comment: When I say "The operation _sequence_ isn't important", 
I mean we can replace X with C then run the function, 
OR run the function on all the Xs then replace X with C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this is what you need.

```
import os
import math

def mmToDegrees(C): # define function
    cylynderDiameter = 2**(2+1)
    decimalPlaces = (2+1)
    rad = cylynderDiameter/2 # equation below uses a radius
    C = round((C/rad)*(180/math.pi), decimalPlaces) #convert mm move to angle in degrees
    return C

def proprecess():
    for line in readFile.readlines():
        line = line.strip().replace('X', 'C').replace('Y-', 'Z')
        num_ = line.split(" ")[0][1:]
        num = float(num_)
        ret = mmToDegrees(num) # call the function
        writeFile.write(line + "\n")
        if 'Z' in line:
            ind = line.find('Z')
            k = line[:ind].replace(num_, str(ret))
            line = k + line[ind:]
        else:
            line = line.replace(num_, str(ret))
        ltimate.write(line + "\n")

if __name__=="__main__":
    pth = r'C:\Users\10696\Desktop\access\origin.txt'
    readFile = open(pth, "r")
    writeFile = open("temporaryTarget.txt", "w")
    ltimate = open("ultimateTarget.txt", "w")
    proprecess()
    readFile.close()
    writeFile.close()
    ltimate.close()
```

the content of origin.txt

```
X3.
X2.5 Y-1.
X2. Y-2.
X5. Y-5.
X-3.
```

Comment: That didn't write anything in both target.txt files. I tried altering the path to `pth = r'iCloud Drive\Desktop\origin.txt'` but got an "IndentationError" at `writeFile = open("temporaryTarget.txt", "w"`

Comment: It is a format problem. not the logic, and the answer is correct

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I believe you, but I don't quite understand. Does it work on your computer, and give the correct output? If so, what "format" should I change to make it work on my computer, please? I'm a newbie...

Comment: the code is running in my local computer macbook pro, not in google cloud disk. so you need paste the whole error message.

Comment: IndentationError should replace indent with space

Comment: After some experimentation, I replaced `if __name__=="__main__":
    pth = r'C:\Users\10696\Desktop\access\origin.txt'` with just`readFile = open("origin.txt", "rt")` and it works perfectly.Thanks.